# Swift 3 Rotate Map With User Direction

Tags: swift, xcode, rotation, android-mapview

Currently my swift Application has a mapview with various annotations, is there a way when the user is walking from various annotations on the map to not be always locked in the north direction? I want the map to turn in the direction that they are walking instead of always pointing north.

Here is my current updatelocation function

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{

    let location = locations[0]
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, noteTime.span)
    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.map.showsUserLocation = true
    map.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.19, green:0.69, blue:0.73, alpha:1.0)
}
```

Should I declare it in here?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapview/1451879-showscompass

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This example will update the rotation of the `mapView` to be pointing in the same direction as the user.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        mapView.camera.heading = newHeading.magneticHeading
        mapView.setCamera(mapView.camera, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Is that what you were after? I hope that helps :)

Comment: How can I rotate the pin instead of the map?

Comment: @Cristina you have to apply the rotation to the annotation image (the pin) instead of the map.